# Is it possible to use a Custom machine for Dataflow instances?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm been reading [creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type) and It seems really interesting but I don't know how to set up a Dataflow streaming job with a custom machine (for example 8 CPUs and 15GB). Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dataflow now supports custom machine types, which can be specified like other machine types, with the `--workerMachineType` flag.

A sample value is `--workerMachineType=custom-8-7424`, which would correspond to 8 cores and  7424 MB of memory.

Comment: Do you know what syntax is required to use the "Extend memory" custom instance option?

Comment: after a bit of digging, I found that "custom-2-15360-ext" will work (ie. just add the -ext suffix).