# Custom Machine Types in Python Dataflow SDK

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

According to [Is it possible to use a Custom machine for Dataflow instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606172/is-it-possible-to-use-a-custom-machine-for-dataflow-instances) you can set the custom machine type for a dataflow operation by specifying the name as `custom-<number of cpus>-<memory in mb>`

But that answer is for the Java Api and the old Dataflow version, not the new Apache Beam implementation and Python.

If I supply `--worker_machine_type custom-8-5376`in the 2.0.0 google-cloud-dataflow python API, I get the following error:

> "(4092fe7df5a10577): The workflow could not be created. Please try again in a few minutes. If you are still unable to create a job please contact customer support. Causes: (4092fe7df5a10596): Unable to get machine type information for machine type custom-8-5376 in zone us-central1-f. Please check that machine type and zone are correct."

I also tried defining a new instance template in the compute engine and supplying the name of that template in the `--worker_machine_type` parameter, but that doesn't work, either.

How can you run a workflow on Dataflow 2.0.0 with a custom machine type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

per custom machine type doc:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type

> The memory per vCPU of a custom machine type must be between 0.9 GB and 6.5 GB per vCPU, inclusive.

So for 8 vCPUs, 7424MiB is the minimum.

Could you please try again?

Comment: I just tried it with 8 cpus and 8GB and that works. Is there no way around this limitation? If I create a custom template in the compute engine page, I can select extended memory and this limitation doesn't seem to apply. I need a machine with 2-4 vCPU's and 80-100GB memory.

Comment: When you create a VM on the compute engine page, you can click Equivalent REST at the very bottom of the page, which has a field `machineType`. If you select Extended memory, the custom machine string becomes `custom-4-102400-ext`. Not sure if Dataflow supports these, but perhaps give it a go