# worker_machine_type tag not working in Google Cloud Dataflow with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using Apache Beam in Python with Google Cloud Dataflow (2.3.0). When specifying the `worker_machine_type` parameter as e.g. `n1-highmem-2` or `custom-1-6656`, Dataflow runs the job but always uses the standard machine type `n1-standard-1` for every worker.

Does anyone have an idea if I am doing something wrong?

Other topics ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211277/custom-machine-types-in-python-dataflow-sdk) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606172/is-it-possible-to-use-a-custom-machine-for-dataflow-instances)) show that this should be possible, so this might be a version issue.

My code for specifying PipelineOptions (note that all other options do work fine, so it should recognize the `worker_machine_type` parameter):

```
def get_cloud_pipeline_options(project):

  options = {
    'runner': 'DataflowRunner',
    'job_name': ('converter-ml6-{}'.format(
        datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))),
    'staging_location': os.path.join(BUCKET, 'staging'),
    'temp_location': os.path.join(BUCKET, 'tmp'),
    'project': project,
    'region': 'europe-west1',
    'zone': 'europe-west1-d',
    'autoscaling_algorithm': 'THROUGHPUT_BASED',
    'save_main_session': True,
    'setup_file': './setup.py',
    'worker_machine_type': 'custom-1-6656',
    'max_num_workers': 3,
  }

  return beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **options)

def main(argv=None):
  args = parse_arguments(sys.argv if argv is None else argv)

  pipeline_options = get_cloud_pipeline_options(args.project_id

  pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PipelineOptions` uses `argparse` behind the scenes to parse its argument. In the case of machine type, the name of the argument is `machine_type` however the flag name is `worker_machine_type`. This works fine in the following two cases, where argparse does its parsing and is aware of this aliasing:

1. Passing arguments on the commandline. e.g. `my_pipeline.py --worker_machine_type custom-1-6656`
2. Passing arguments as a command line flags e.g. `flags['--worker_machine_type', 'worker_machine_type custom-1-6656', ...]`

However it does not work well with `**kwargs`. Any additional args passed in that way are used to substitute for known argument names (but not flag names).

In short, using `machine_type` would work everywhere. I filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4112 for this to be fixed in Beam in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by using the flag `machine_type` instead of `worker_machine_type`. The rest of the code works fine.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params) is thus mentioning the wrong field name.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in Apache Beam 2.8.0 was to update [this line](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.8.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L459) of the source code by changing `--worker_machine_type` to `--machine_type` (and then using `machine_type` as the name of the parameter, as suggested in the other answers).